# I'm not able to provide ViewModel

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm not able to provide LoginViewModel using LoginViewModelProviderModule when I include LoginViewModelProviderModule in     `@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainFragmentBuilderModule::class, LoginViewModelProviderModule::class])` but it works when I include it in @Module annotation in ActivityBuilderModule class.

**BaseApplicationComponent**

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityBuilderModule::class,
        ViewModelFactoryModule::class]
)
interface BaseApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<BaseApplicationClass> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): BaseApplicationComponent
    }
}
```

**ActivityBuilderModule**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {

    @LoginScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainFragmentBuilderModule::class, LoginViewModelProviderModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

**MainFragmentBuilderModule**

```
@Module
abstract class MainFragmentBuilderModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributesLoginFragment(): LoginFragment
}
```

**LoginViewModelProviderModule**

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class LoginViewModelProviderModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(LoginViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindLoginViewModel(viewModel: LoginViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

**ViewModelFactoryModule**

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelProviderFactory: ViewModelProviderFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

**ViewModelProviderFactory**

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelProviderFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass") as Throwable
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginScope**

```
@Scope
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class LoginScope
```

**ViewModelKey**

```
@MustBeDocumented
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

**This is the error that I see:**

error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map,javax.inject.Provider> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface BaseApplicationComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector {
                ^
      java.util.Map,javax.inject.Provider> is injected at
          com.example.mydemoapplication.viewmodel_factory.ViewModelProviderFactory(creators)
      com.example.mydemoapplication.viewmodel_factory.ViewModelProviderFactory is injected at
          com.example.mydemoapplication.LoginFragment.viewModelProviderFactory
      com.example.mydemoapplication.LoginFragment is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.example.mydemoapplication.dagger.BaseApplicationComponent ? com.example.mydemoapplication.dagger.ActivityBuilderModule_ContributeMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent ? com.example.mydemoapplication.dagger.MainFragmentBuilderModule_ContributesLoginFragment.LoginFragmentSubcomponent]

Comment: update - `ViewModelProviderFactory` should not be Singleton and removing this fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can only create a module bind all of viewmodel in application. You can see detail in my sample app:
[sample-moviedb-app](https://github.com/tuandao2511/MovieDB_43)

**BaseApplicationComponent:**

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityBuilderModule::class,
        ViewModelFactoryModule::class,
        ViewModelModule::class]

)
interface BaseApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<BaseApplicationClass> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): BaseApplicationComponent
    }
}
```

**ViewModelModule:**

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class ViewModelProviderModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(LoginViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindLoginViewModel(viewModel: LoginViewModel): ViewModel

//other viewmodels in application
   @Binds
   abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelProviderFactory:ViewModelProviderFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

**MainModule:**

```
@Module
class MainModule {
    @MainActivityScope
    @Provides
    fun provideViewModel(mainActivity: MainActivity, viewModelFactory: ViewModelProviderFactory) =
        ViewModelProviders.of(mainActivity, viewModelFactory).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
}
```

**LoginViewModel:**

```
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
) : ViewModel() {

}
```